# MySQL: ошибка создания триггера

Tags: mysql, триггер

Помогите создать триггер, не понимаю, в чём ошибка....

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER trInsRaboty AFTER INSERT ON Raboty
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
SET AUTOCOMMIT=0;
START TRANSACTION;
IF (select count(*) from Raboty where (IdRabot = new.IdRabot))<VidyRabot.KolvoSotrudnikov
then (Insert raboty values(null,new.IdVidaRabot,new.IdSotrudnika,new.DataNach,(select Dni_NaVypolnenie from VidyRabot where idVidaRabot=new.IdVidaRabot)+new.DataNach););
Else ROLLBACK;
EndIF;
COMMIT;
END; //
DELIMITER ;
COMMIT; 
END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

**Добавлено из комментария.**

Нет, выглядит оно построчно (через консоль работаю)
ошибка вида

> `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select IdSotrudnika from Raboty where (IdRabot = new.IdRabot))<VidyRabot.KolvoSo' at line 5`

Comment: А оно так и выглядит, в одну строку? (1) Что-за ошибка-то (2)

Comment: Перенесено в вопрос.

Comment: Что у Вас за IF? синтаксис функции if, а используется там, где должен бы быть оператор IF STATEMENT

Comment: А если так? ругаемся на Insert...

Comment: А что такое new.IdRabot? Да и вообще, триггер AFTER INSERT ON Raboty, в котором выполняется INSERT raboty...

Answer (score 1):

Ошибок несколько, это и синтаксические ошибки, связанные с расстановкой скобок, и ошибки использования операторов транзакций. Дело в том, что в триггерах нельзя использовать транзакции, а в вашем случае в этом нет необходимости, так как все операции атомарны и "не портят" базу данных, следовательно и откатываться некуда. После очистки ваш триггер может выглядеть следующим образом

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER trInsRaboty AFTER INSERT ON Raboty
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF (SELECT
        COUNT(*)
      FROM
        Raboty
      WHERE (IdRabot = NEW.IdRabot)) < VidyRabot.KolvoSotrudnikov THEN
    INSERT INTO
      Raboty
    VALUES (
      NULL,
      NEW.IdVidaRabot,
      NEW.IdSotrudnika,
      NEW.DataNach,
      (SELECT
         Dni_NaVypolnenie
       FROM
         VidyRabot
       WHERE
         idVidaRabot = NEW.IdVidaRabot) + NEW.DataNach );
   END IF;
END//
```

Возможно вы хотели отменить транзакцию вставки основной записи, но это это точно следует делать не в AFTER-триггере, который срабатывает после вставки записи. Для этих целей лучше рассмотреть BEFORE-фильтр.